# How do I change my level after a certain score has been reached? (Java, NetBeans)

Tags: java

I already have some part of the code but I'm not sure whether or not it's okay like this. I need to change it somehow because it doesn't work like this. This is my current code;

```java
public void changeLevel(){
        for(int i = 1; i < getScore(); i++){
            if(getScore() % 100 == 0){
                level++;
            }
        } 
    }
```

In this case, every time after 100 points I want my level to add 1.
If anybody could help me out, that would be hugely appreciated! :)

Comment: What happens if your score jumps to 1,105?  You can just calculate level based on any increment, not just 100. `level = (getScore + 99) / 100;`

Comment: The loop does not make any use of the value of `i`. Why would you want to test the same `getScore() % 100 == 0` condition `getScore()` times ?

Answer (score 0):

Please Consider below example,

```
public class Person {
    private Integer score;
    private Integer level;

    public void changeLevel(){
        this.level = this.score / 100 > 0 ? this.level + this.score / 100 : this.level;
        this.score = this.score % 100;
    }

    public Person(Integer score, Integer level) {
        this.score = score;
        this.level = level;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "score=" + score +
                ", level=" + level +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And you may validate result as,

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person person = new Person(427, 2);
    person.changeLevel();
    System.out.println(person);
}
```

}

Comment: Sure, good point.

Answer (score -1):

The level change code should rather be related to the score change code.

Something like :

```java
public class Person {
    private int score = 0;
    private int level = 0;

    public void incrementScore() {
        if (++this.score % 100 == 0) ++this.level;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person person = new Person();
        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++) person.incrementScore();
        System.out.println("Person score: " + person.score);
        System.out.println("Person level: " + person.level);
    }
}
```

Comment: it definitely not work mate, you need to add if result to this.level like: "this.level = this.score % 100 == 0 ? this.level+1 : this.level;"

Comment: @Lunatic yes that is what this code does : "++this.level" increments the value of this.level

Comment: And then overwritten object in heap out scoped by stack and saved no where, seems its not the case no one want ay ? ~.~

Comment: @Lunatic `this.level` is indeed an instance variable. Its scope is not limited to the method. Maybe I'm missing your point ?

Comment: mate, the result of adding this.level saves no where and pointer to new value "++this.level"  out scoped and equivalently the related object eliminates.  all we need is to save the  modified value to proper pointer "this.value".

Comment: @Lunatic ok I see the confusion : I'm implicitly using primitive type "int" whereas you are using reference type Integer. Let me edit my code to explicit this.